# Why is puppeteer $(<selector>) not working?

Tags: puppeteer

I am using pupteer to select a field input with the name of website. When i select it and then use the click method i keep getting an error message that says "website_input.click is not a function "

But when i try to do this

```
 page.type("input[name='website']","test");
```

it works fine which i find very weird. Below is the code i am using. Any help would be really appreciated

```
const website_input = page.$("input[name='website']");
    await website_input.click({clickCount: 3});
    await website_input.press('Backspace');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be related to promises. You should await it and then work with the element:

```js
const website_input = await page.$("input[name='website']");
await website_input.click({clickCount: 3});
await website_input.press('Backspace');
```

That's because `page.$()` method returns `Promise<ElementHandle<T> | null>`, not just element handle. You can check the [docs](https://puppeteer.github.io/puppeteer/docs/puppeteer.page._).

Comment: Oh  man thanks man.

Comment: I totally missed that

Comment: @json2021: no worries, it happens somethimes :) good it works now